# how can I listen to a channel event of a websocket server being a client in c# using the library WebSocketSharp?

Tags: c#, laravel, unity-game-engine, websocket, websocket-sharp

I can connect to the server but I can't receive any message from a specific channel and event.

I'm working in c# with the websocket sharp library. Should I change library?  The server uses php and laravel

The following code works in java, I need to do the same for c# but don't know how to do this specific

In java this works:

window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: '123456',
cluster: 'mt1',
forceTLS: true,
wsHost: 'ws.test.bet',
wsPort: 6781,
enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
})

```
  window.Echo.channel('events').listen('RealTimeEvent', (e) => console.log(' Message: ' + e.message)
```

Comment: by `java` you mean `JavaScript`, right? Note that those are two different languages ^^

Comment: And well .. what have you tried? The [examples](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp#usage) look pretty self-explanatory to me ... If this is in a WebGL solution though: Why not stick to the JavaScript side code and rather invoke a callback in c# passing on the data - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html